# Cognito Forms: Country field with drop-down menu

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to add a country drop-down menu in my form without having to use the full address container which has many fields which I don't need for my application. Is there any way how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We do not have a drop down specifically for countries outside of the country drop down in the address field.

You can use a normal Choice Filed, and a list of countries. The list wont have to be entered in one by one rather you can copy the list, and paste it into the first choice of the Choice Field. This will populate the list down, each item will be its own option.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, The possibility to copy and paste the full list into a standard choice field wasn't known to me. This will resolve my problem copmpletely.